PolyglotException in Karate when certain json key has hyphen "-"
When a key within the json object has hyphen, possibly it is causing an issue with Karate. Here is an example -
{
  "id": "1234",
  "type": "FICTION",
  "attribute": {
    "bookPrice": "10",
    "authorName": {
      "firstName": "Dean",
      "lastName": "Jones"
    },
    "links": {
      "get-book-by-id": {
        "href": "/v1/books/1234",
        "title": "get-book-by-id"
      }
    }
  }
}

In this example, the key "get-book-by-id" is seperated by hyphen and when I try to travers to this element, I am getting an error something like below -
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: 'book' is not defined.


refer https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+hyphen

Feature: Sample

  Scenario: Test1
    * def response =
      """
      {
        "id": "1234",
        "type": "FICTION",
        "attribute": {
          "bookPrice": "10",
          "authorName": {
            "firstName": "Dean",
            "lastName": "Jones"
          },
          "links": {
            "get-book-by-id": {
              "href": "/v1/books/1234",
              "title": "get-book-by-id"
            }
          }
        }
      }
      """
    
    * print response.attribute.links["get-book-by-id"]


thanks a lot... much better than me thinking of using a custom Java type.
